# Chi-Squared 2 ordinal variable how to sum up categories in R?

Tags: chi-squared, ordinal

I'm completely new to statistics and just wrestle with testing some data I recently collected.

The picture below shows you the kind of material I'm having. For the first test I just want to run a Chi squared on two ordinal variables (satisfied_scale and time_scale). Both have 1(totally agree) to 5 (totally disagree), but since I don't have too much data I'd need to sum them up to three groups (1+2, 3, 4+5), it's just that I don't know how to do that in R. It's a little embarrassing to ask that, but I already spent two hours looking for that and didn't want to lose even more time.

I converted these 2 vectors to factor and added some labels.

Now when I get I put them into a table I get this (probably obvious for you guys ;-):

```
           tim_scale
sat_scale  time++ time+ time time- time--
  v. sat        3     4    1     4      0
  sat           2     3    3     5      1
  ntrl          2     0    1     2      3
  unsat         2     1    2     0      1
  v. unsat      2     0    0     1      0
```

When I run the chi-squared test like this:

```
chisq.test(toTab)
```

I get this:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  toTab
X-squared = 17.5486, df = 16, p-value = 0.351

Warning message:
In chisq.test(toTab) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

So, how I can I sum up those categories to get better results?

Edit: the first line should actually contain a proper greeting, but somehow it always gets cut off, no matter how often I edit it.

[image: data_material_last2ColumnsOfInterest]